# secure boot problem on acer nitro 5 (2021)

Tags: boot, uefi, amd-ryzen

Trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 on an acer nitro 5 (amd ryzen 5600hs and nvidia GTX 3060.

set up a password as requested during install, then re-enter the password on first boot to setup the keys, but when it reboots it just sits forever on the acer splash screen.

Any ideas?

May try 21.04 in case it has a newer setup.......

I [followed the info here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot).

Comment: With Nvidia hardware, did you turn off secure boot or did you try to enter your own keys?  Have you checked the vendor site for firmware updates?  Definitely try the 21.04 for the newest hardware support.

Comment: As above. More often than not even new hardware needs updates. And it's much easier to disable Secure Boot.

Comment: Yeah, disabled secure boot and all went smoothly

Answer (score 0):

I took the easy way and just disabled secure boot, then everything was fine - apart from no drivers for the wifi chipset (yet).